# why "$B[[u]]$ is flat over $B \otimes_A A[[u]]$ "?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Lemma:**

> If $A$ is a Noetherian and $A \to B$ is an fppf morphism, then  the induced $A[[u]] \to B[[u]]$ is faithfully flat.

**Proof:**

> Note that $B[[u]]$ is flat over $B \otimes_A A[[u]]$ (being $u$-adic completion of the latter ring, which is finitely presented over the Noetherian ring $A[[u]]$, and thus is Noetherian itself), which in turn flat over $A[[u]]$. ( proof continues$\cdots \cdots$)

This is collected from a paper.

But I did not understand why "$B[[u]]$ is flat over $B \otimes_A A[[u]]$ " ?

Because here $B[[u]]$ is a ring and so how to describe its flatness?

> I am thinking, that if $M,N$ be two $B \otimes_A A[[u]]$-module and if $P$ be any $B[[u]]$-module and if $\phi:M \to N$ be injective then $M \otimes_{B \otimes_A A[[u]]} P \to N \otimes_{B \otimes_A A[[u]]} P$ is also injective. That means I am trying to show that every module over $B[[u]]$ is flat and hence it is flat ring. Is it true what I am saying?

How to see that $B[[u]]$ is an $u$-adic completion of $B \otimes_A A[[u]]$ ?

Kindly help me an explanation why "$B[[u]]$ is flat over $B \otimes_A A[[u]]$ " ?

Comment: **fppf** stands for what?

Comment: @user26857, it is a faithfully flat morphism

Comment: No, that is not the entirety what fppf stands for: fppf is a French abbreviation for "fidèlement plate de présentation finie", or faithfully flat of finite presentation.

Comment: @KReiser, yes you are right. I missed the words "finite presentation"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're unaware of how one ring may be flat over another ("[b]ecause here $B[[u]]$ is a ring and so how to describe its flatness?"), it's probably a good idea to review that first:

> A ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ gives $S$ the structure of an $R$-module by defining the $R$-action on $S$ as $r\cdot s = f(r)s$ where the multiplication on the right is the multiplication in $S$. We then declare $f$ to make $S$ a flat $R$-module if $S$ is flat as an $R$-module via the module structure given by $f$.

The correct strategy to resolve your question is to recall a foundational result from commutative algebra:

> **Lemma**(Stacks [00MB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MB)): Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal. Assume $R$ is noetherian. Then $R^\wedge$, the completion of $R$ with respect to $I$, is a flat $R$-module.

This means that if we can show that $B[[u]]$ is (isomorphic to) the completion of $B\otimes_A A[[u]]$ with respect to the ideal $(1\otimes u)$, then we'll be done. This is straightforwards: the completion $R^\wedge$ is defined as the inverse limit of $R/I^n$ as $n$ varies. It is straightforwards to see that $(B\otimes_A A[[u]])/(1\otimes u)^n\cong B\otimes_A (A[u]/(u^n))\cong B[u]/(u^n)$ which clearly has inverse limit $B[[u]]$. Thus $B[[u]]$ is the completion of $B\otimes_A A[[u]]$ and is flat over it.

Comment: $(1\otimes u)$ is an ideal of $B\otimes_A A[[u]]$, not $B[[u]]$. What's going on here is that I'm using the isomorphism $(B\otimes_A A[[u]])^\wedge\cong B[[u]]$ to identify $1\otimes u \in (B\otimes_A A[[u]])^\wedge$ with $u\in B[[u]]$. The rest of your comment seems to be based on a misunderstanding of this and doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: ohh, yes. I misunderstood it. I thought the ideal is of the ring $B[[u]]$, but i is not. Now it is clear